# Converting a velocity variable to java.lang.String

Tags: java, variables, velocity, meta-tags

I have a velocity variable "topic.url" inside a jsp page. This code happens to be written by some other person so I am not very sure where exactly this variable came from. Anyway this variable gives me a particular URL which I have to parse and extract particular field. I am planning to write a java function to do this. The problem is when I pass this velocity variable to the function what datatype should I use. I tried converting it into string but that does not work. Here's the snippet of the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<%!

public String parse(String url)
{
    url="abc";  
    return(url);
}
%>

    <meta name="email.subject" content="Community name:{community.name},Topic Name:{topic.name},Topic URL:<%= parse({topic.url}) %>">
</head>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "does not work"? errors? nothing happens? tell us your observation.

Comment: Maybe it is not a String, could be a URL for example. Change the String parameter to Object and see what it is.

Comment: It throws an error saying the argument is not a string. I tried passing it as an object also still the same error that the argument is not an object.

Comment: Maybe add quotes? <%= parse("{topic.url}") %>

Comment: Wouldnt it be passed as a normal string if I add quotes. how would I get the value then?

Answer (score 1):

A Velocity variable inside a jsp page???  Then it's not a velocity variable.  It's a jsp var.  You are either writing VTL or JSP.  You can embed VTL in a JSP with the VelocityViewTag, but that's the only way to have a Velocity variable inside a JSP.  And that doesn't look like the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot pass a velocity template parameter to the function with such syntax:

```
<%= parse({topic.url}) %>
```

You could try the approach below instead.  Note that there is almost certainly a much better way to do get this job done, using tools that Velocity provides.  The below is kind of and ugly hack to get you up and running.  I highly suggest reworking this approach to better leverage Velocity's facilities:

```
public String parseTopicUrl(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    Object topic = request.getAttribute("topic");
    if (topic == null) {
        System.out.println(">>>null topic");
        return null;
    }
    Class topicClass = topic.getClass();
    java.lang.reflect.Method method = topicClass.getMethod("getUrl", null);
    Object url = method.invoke(topic, null);
    if (url == null) {
        System.out.println(">>>'url' is null");
    } else {
        System.out.println(">>>'url' class is " + url.getClass());
        System.out.println(">>>'url' toString is " + url);
    }
    // TODO: cast 'url' to its real class and work with it
    return null;
}
```

Then use:

```
<%= parseTopicUrl(request) %>
```

Comment: I tried passing it as an Object to the function but it still throws an error saying that the variable cannot be converted to an object.

Comment: Updated answer in response to your comment.

Comment: <html>
<head>
<%!

public String parseTopicUrl() throws Exception { 
    Object topic = request.getAttribute("topic"); 
        .......... 
    } 
        return null; 
} 
%>

 <meta name="email.subject" content="Community name:{community.name},Topic Name:{topic.name},Topic URL:<%= parseTopicURL() %>">
</head>

Comment: Nisha, I am pretty sure my approach isn't the best way to do this with Velocity.  However, it might still work.  I have updated my answer again to try and fix the 'request' not found issue.  Notice the changes to both the method _and_ the `<%= parseTopicUrl(request) %>`.  Be sure to take both changes.

Comment: <%= parseTopicUrl(request) %> This cannot be done in Velocity.

Comment: @Mike.. I tried the new solution. Its recieving topic as null..as in it goes inside the if loop topic==null. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot write Java functions inside a velocity template. You would have to retort to Velocity macro. Else write a factory method and it should be available in Velocity context.

Comment: I am new to velocity concept. I just know that the variable I am using is a velocity variable and this is inside a jsp page. Its used inside the meta tag. I need to pass it to a java function.

Comment: I would suggest you read documentation http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/developer-guide.html. Velocity accepts map set in the context. The string should be set in the velocity context. You can make method calls on the objects available in the context. Which implies that if String object is available you can invoke all related methods on it. If you intend to perform Regex action even that object would have to be set in the context.

Answer (score 0):

nisha, wht if u totally removed d jsp code & instead found out wht data / object type topic.url is and used its method directly inside d braces? lets assume that it is a string. what if u used sthg like {topic.url.substring(index where id starts)} to extract the id out of d url ?

i mean e.g.
<meta name="email.subject" content="Community name:{community.name},Topic Name:{topic.name},Topic URL:{topic.url.substring(30)}">

bottom line, i mean just use d appropriate data type specific methods within d braces.

Comment: That approach does not work...it displays topic.url.substring(30) as it is. I dont think it understands its a java function

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming quite late for the answear but I had a similar problem. I ended up realising that velocity was looking for the "getUrl" method for my "something.url", whereas the actual method name was "getURL" -notice uppercase-. In that case you just have to explicitly write "${something.getURL()}" instead of the former "${something.url}".

That solved it for me.